# DataTable not rendering properly on small device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatable

I have a Data-table properly working, but the issue I am facing is when I am using the same table on small device its not working fine

**Snippet**

```js
var data = [{
    "amount": 518212,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104801,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 138151,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 628358,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 115223,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 134107,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 177866,
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 66095,
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 284069,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58789,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 67886,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 313128,
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 59939,
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 68558,
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 321797,
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 64431,
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 57352,
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 323556,
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58772,
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 43722,
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 464127,
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 93110,
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 62213,
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 626772,
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 126933,
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 63119,
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 167391,
    "billdate": "2018-08-13",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 27110,
    "billdate": "2018-08-13",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 275115,
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58633,
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 37920,
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  }
];
var columndef = [{
  title: "amount",
  data: "amount"
}, {
  title: "billdate",
  data: "billdate"
}, {
  title: "outlet",
  data: "outlet"
}];
$('#tbl').DataTable({
  columns: columndef,
  data: data,
  scrollY: '50vh',
  scrollCollapse: true,
  paging: false
});
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table id="tbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered "></table>
```

Now what happens on big devices it is working fine, but when I use that on small device the `tbody` part properly scrolls horizontally but the `thead` part is static which is not looking good on `ui`.

To replicate the issue, resize the browser and scroll horizontally Is there an alternate resource I can use for this?

Comment: Have you added the view port tags ? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @ThivankaW yup i have added in my code

Comment: is your thead's overflowing out of the current view port when using small devices ?

Comment: @ThivankaW  yupp like that..you just check my snippet please,and resize the browser,you will find the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding a `scrollX: "100%"` (usually you need a `scrollX` if you use `scrollY`) to your `datatables` options as well as `width: 100%` to your table in your css, this should fix your issue. Please check the code below and the fiddle linked at the bottom.

```js
var data = [{
    "amount": 518212,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104801,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 138151,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 628358,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 115223,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 134107,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 177866,
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 66095,
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 284069,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58789,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 67886,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 313128,
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 59939,
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 68558,
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 321797,
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 64431,
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 57352,
    "billdate": "2018-08-09",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 323556,
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58772,
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 43722,
    "billdate": "2018-08-10",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 464127,
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 93110,
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 62213,
    "billdate": "2018-08-11",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 626772,
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 126933,
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 63119,
    "billdate": "2018-08-12",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 167391,
    "billdate": "2018-08-13",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 27110,
    "billdate": "2018-08-13",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 275115,
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58633,
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 37920,
    "billdate": "2018-08-14",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  }
];
var columndef = [{
  title: "amount",
  data: "amount"
}, {
  title: "billdate",
  data: "billdate"
}, {
  title: "outlet",
  data: "outlet"
}];
$('#tbl').DataTable({
  columns: columndef,
  "columnDefs": [{
    "className": "dt-left",
    "targets": "_all"
  }],
  data: data,
  scrollY: "50vh",
  responsive: true,
  paging: false,
  scrollX: "100%",
  scrollCollapse: true
});
```

```css
#tbl {
  width: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table id="tbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered "></table>
```

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bucvf6ek/2/